# the_post_thumbnail('medium') still gives thumbnail-size img

Tags: post-thumbnails, images

All the sources mention this as if it worked.

Medium size is set to 635x194, but I still get this out:

```
<img width="100" height="100" title="fjaril" alt="fjaril" class="attachment-thumbnail" src="http://blogg.nassjo.se/klassblogg/files/2012/12/fjaril-100x100.jpg">
```

As you see, it hard-links to the shrunken thumbnail size. Docs say I should get a class matching the size argument in the img HTML also.

Where should I look, and what to fix?

I'm just trying to get the first post on the front page to display its featured image medium-sized. I'm modifying content.php in the theme. I can search-and-replace, but that would break if the customer changes thumbnail sizes.

The website is here: http://blogg.nassjo.se/

**Update:**

Just made a **child theme**, and there, it works as it should.

See http://blogg.nassjo.se/klassblogg/

**Update 2**
I made a child theme for the main site also, but that did (unexpectedly) *not* make it work. I have to conclude that the_post_thumbnail('medium') only works on the site where it was posted.

I've put the img html in a var and search/replaced to get the medium size and url, and that hack works.

I'll leave the question up for a bit, in case someone can help me find the real reason so I can remove the hack.

Comment: What are the dimensions of the full-size image?

Comment: In this case,635x194.

Answer (score 1):

Install [Regenerate Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/). Run it once, and see if your images are being generated.

Feel free to keep the plugin installed for future use. (it won't break anything if you *do* uninstall it after you're done)

Comment: I like [Force Regenerate Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/force-regenerate-thumbnails/), an extension of the original. Gets rid of unneeded sizes as well.

Comment: The images are there and in the correct size. I can say that because {the_post_thumbnail('medium');} works in the child theme (see update).

Answer (score 0):

Does `medium` size exist? you can check by vardumping the global:
`global $_wp_additional_image_sizes;`

An other possibility is that the filter `post_thumbnail_html` is screwing something up.

Also can you add the code that returns this `<img />` tag?

Comment: The code is in the question title :) var_dump gives an array with 4 sizes, including 'medium'.

Comment: try disabeling plugins to see is one of them brakes it.

Comment: Edited the question with important information. I'm currently only using Sitewide Tags and WPMU Site Categories, but I will test.